# Clearing Elements in SVG group

Tags: javascript, html, svg

So I have a program that is drawing circles to represent charges, and it can also draw electric field lines and field magnitude lines. However, I want to add in the functionality of being able to erase all of the field lines and leave the charges, or erase all of the elements. Everything that is drawn goes into this svg:

```
<svg version="1.1" id="svg" x="0px" y="0px"
        width="710px" height="510px" viewBox="0 0 710 510" style="enable-background:new 0 0 700 500;" xml:space="preserve" onmouseup="mouseUp(evt)">
            <defs>
            <marker id="markerArrow" viewBox="0 0 10 10" refX="1" refY="5"
                markerWidth="6" markerHeight="6" orient="auto">
                <path d="M 0 0 L 10 5 L 0 10 z" />
            </defs>
            <g id="gridLineGroup"></g>
            <g id="fieldLineGroup"></g>
            <g id="chargesGroup"></g>
        </svg>
```

As you can see, there are groups created for each of the different types of drawings. So once I want to clear any one of those three groups, I want it to delete all of the elements in that group but leave it to be filled up again. I don't want the user to have to restart the webpage to redo any mess ups. I've looked around a lot and have been unable to find a solution that works for my program. It is a stock html program.

The latest function I tried to run was a button click that ran this function:

```
function clearLines() {
            document.getElementById("svg").removeChild("fieldLineGroup");
        }
```

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/mattbatman/1vqkgqp4/.

I used `remove` over the collection instead of `removeChild`.

I selected all paths within the group, made the selection an array so I could iterate over it with `forEach`, and called `remove` on each element:

```
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const paths = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('g#gridLineGroup path'));
  paths.forEach(path => { path.remove(); });
});
```

Comment: Thank you Matt. I do want to make a not however. Instead of exactly what you wrote, I put the code inside of you action listener into its own function. From there I just put an onclick call to the function in the definition to my button. That way I can actually have multiple buttons call the same function.